# How can I test through a number of sibling nodes to see if they match a variable?

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, xslt-1.0

I need to check a variable against a directory to see if any of those sibling nodes have an attribute that's equal to the variable.  I know that '=' and 'contain' don't work with wildcards so I was thinking of using for-each along with choose, but I don't know how to create some sort of variable or marker that tells me if there's a match or not.

Comment: Do you have some example code we can see? It will also help to know what you've tried and what you haven't.

Answer (score 0):

Use a predicate with the `contains` function to check for existence. For example:

```
<file>photo</file>
<path name="local">desktop</path>
```

In this case, use the `following-sibling` axis with the asterisk to check all siblings of the `file` node which have attribute nodes, then use the predicate to check for the existence of the string `local` in the set of node values:

```
//file/following-sibling::*/@*[contains(../@*, 'local')]"
```

The variable would just replace the string:

```
//file/following-sibling::*/@*[contains(../@*, $foo)]"
```

**References**

- [MDN: XPath Axes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Axes)